# How to connect to existing database? .NET Core API & SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, api, .net-core

Good day!

I am struggling on how to connect existing database with existing data to my API project. And also how do I know if I'm already connected? I am using .NET Core 1.1 and my database is SQL Server 2012.

[image]

appsettings.json :

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "DefaultConnection": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=;User Id=sa;Password=Passw0rd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
    }
  }
}
```

Startup.cs - ConfigureServices

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddDbContext<DefaultConnection>(
    options => options.UseSqlServer(
    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
}
```

I am following this tutorial but it seems that this creates new database.
http://www.mithunvp.com/aspnet-core-web-api-entity-framework-core/

Would highly appreciate all your comments/solutions/suggestions.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Using a '.' is the same as using localhost - not sure if that is causing you issues? Is SQL installed on the machine you are trying to connect with? Either way, I would specify the server name instead of '.'

Comment: Change `Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS` to `Server=COGSOL-LAP13`... Read [ask], explain very explicitly what is and isn't working ("I am struggling" is not a proper problem description), and show what you have tried.

Comment: If you're not sure about your connection string format, check out https://www.connectionstrings.com/. That site will be a huge help with ensuring that all the parameters are set properly.

Comment: @CodeCaster Apologies Sir. And thank you for your reply

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the name of the database into that line :

```
 "DefaultConnection": "Server=COGSOL-LAP13;Database=DATABASENAME;UserId=sa;Password=Passw0rd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

And as CodeCaster comment says, you should use the name of the server too

You also have a space between User and Id  `User Id` should be

> UserId